# net.pipe service host in WPF app

Tags: wpf, wcf, net.pipe

The contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDaemonService {
    [OperationContract]
    void SendNotification(DaemonNotification notification);
}
```

The service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class DaemonService : IDaemonService {
    public DaemonService() {
    }

    public void SendNotification(DaemonNotification notification) {
        App.NotificationWindow.Notify(notification);
    }
}
```

In WPF app I do the following:

```
using (host = new ServiceHost(typeof (DaemonService), new[] {new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")})) {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IDaemonService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "AkmDaemon");                
            host.Open();
        }
```

This WPF app launches another app like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                var tpm = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "TPM" } };
                tpm.Start();
                }
            });
```

The app named TPM starts properly. Then I do attach to process in the debugging menu of Visual Studio and I see the client says that nobody is listening at the endpoint.

Here is the client:

```
 [Export(typeof(DaemonClient))]
public class DaemonClient : IHandle<DaemonNotification> {
    private readonly ChannelFactory<IDaemonService> channelFactory;
    private readonly IDaemonService daemonServiceChannel;

    public DaemonClient(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {           
        EventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        EventAggregator.Subscribe(this);

        channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDaemonService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/AkmDaemon"));            
        daemonServiceChannel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; private set; }

    public void Handle(DaemonNotification message) {
        daemonServiceChannel.SendNotification(message); //Here I see that the endpoint //is not found
    }

    public void Close() {
        channelFactory.Close();
    }
}
```

EndpointNotFoundException There was no endpoint listening at "net.pipe://localhost/AkmDaemon"... blablabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your ServiceHost in a `using` statement, so it is disposed right after the `Open` call. The [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343302.aspx) call closes the ServiceHost.

```
using (host = new ServiceHost(...))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(...);
    host.Open();
}
// ServiceHost.Dispose() called here
```

Just drop the using block.

Comment: oh, I was tired it seems to be :)